# When do I know they're ready to give birth

Tags: behavior, aquarium, fish, breeding

How do I know when my platy fish (Xiphophorus variatus) are going to give birth in the next few days?

Comment: you need to give more information like how long have they been pregnant.and do a search on this site to see if this have been asked before and it have multiple times.